# How add request id

Tags: json, extjs, request

I want to send data to the server in Json format.
This my data:

```
var request = {            
    bookId: grid.getBookId(),          
    info: []
}       
store.each(function(rec, index, length) {            
    request.info.push({
        requestId: rec.get('???'),
        authorId: rec.get('authorId'),
        price: rec.get('price')
    });       
});
```

I have data for bookId, authorId, price, but where can I get requestId?

I want to get the numbers that are marked RED on the picture (network in the Developer Tools in Chrome browser)

[image: Developer Tools Screenshot from Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
store.each(function(rec, index, length) {
    // index argument contains number you are looking for
    // for the current item
});
```

Comment: i am should write so requestId:rec.get('index') ? but this don't work ((

Comment: No, just plain `requestId: index`.